# Conversion of HTML5 to LaTex

Tags: html, latex2html

Is anyone familiar with a tool for converting HTML to LaTex markup?

I don't mean fetching and attempting to render CSS stuff, just converting the content of elements like paragraphs, headers, and images.

Maybe a tool which approximates the inverse function of latex2html?

Comment: [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org)? As in, `pandoc -s foo.html -o foo.tex`.

Comment: Pandoc is an amazing tool. Thanks for the info, this solves a lot of problems.